# Accidentally crashed my website in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7

I was just editing my website, and was playing around with themes. I installed the Bootstrap 3 theme. When I set it to default, the website crashed! .Now i am not able to visit or login to my website .I kept getting this error message:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '))' at line 1: SELECT n.uid AS uid, n.created AS created FROM
>   {node} n WHERE (n.status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (n.type IN
>   ()) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in
>   _archive_post_count() (line 385 of /home/eric/public_html/medics/sites/all/modules/archive/archive.module).

Even i am unable to go to admin page.

Please help me!

Comment: try drush commands if you have terminal access.

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem seems to be not in Bootstrap theme, but rather in Archive module. I think that problem is here: `AND (n.type IN ())`
2. Try to clear the cache by visiting www.your-site.com/update.php and them try to open www.your-site.com/admin/modules directly and disable this module.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,i visited www.your-site.com/update.php & but when i tried to visit www.your-site.com/admin/modules directly ,it's displaying the error message. " PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {variable} variable WHERE ( (name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; drupal_http_request_fails ) in variable_set() (line 991 of /home/dreamvip/public_html/www.website.com/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc)".

Comment: Drupal 7 admin page showing  Error as :

" Error message PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {variable} variable WHERE ( (name = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ); Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => drupal_http_request_fails ) in variable_set() (line 991 of /home/dreamvip/public_html/mywebsite.com/drupal/includes/bootstrap.inc).
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Comment: `MySQL server has gone away` means that Drupal can't connect to the databse. Check your settings.php and database connection.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the cache from drush .
1. Go to your folder in terminal.
2. Type **drush cc all**.
3. If nothing happens then change the theme from Terminal using drush  using
       `drush vset admin_theme bartik`